# How to populate SKRouteSettings.alternativeRoutesModes array in Skobbler

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, skmaps

When I search for a route and have alternative routes option checked, skobbler will draw all alternative routes on the map and even start the navigation on the best one, if needed.

But I want to have all those alternative routes stored in an array and leave it to user to select which one he would use.

In the documentation I have noticed an array called alternativeRoutesModes.
But I don't know how exactly and when to populate it.

For a start, this is how I start making a route settings:

```
_route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];

_route.startCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.209877, -108.966310);
_route.destinationCoordinate = _endTravelpoint.coordinate;
_route.shouldBeRendered = YES; 
_route.routeMode = SKRouteCarFastest;
_route.numberOfRoutes = 5;

[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:_route];
```

Now, what exactly should I do with alternativeRoutesModes. Should I declare it before I call calculateRoute?

In the documentation it says:

> Route calculation modes for alternative routes, an array of SKRouteAlternativeSettings objects. If nil, default alternatives will be generated.

Also, when I calculate route, only accessible objects from delegate methods are:

```
(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation*)routeInformation

(void)routingServiceDidFailRouteCalculation:(SKRoutingService *)routingService

(void)routingServiceDidCalculateAllRoutes:(SKRoutingService *)routingService
```

All of this methods have SKRoutingService objects, and not SKRouteService object, from which I could pull out desired array.

Can I get an example of how to populate SKRouteSettings.alternativeRoutesModes with alternative route objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the AlternativeRoutesViewController class in the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download), it contains the same implementation as to what you're looking for.

The [alternativeRoutesModes](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.2.0/Classes/SKRouteSettings.html#//api/name/alternativeRoutesModes) property can be used for advanced route configuration.
e.g. If you want to calculate 3 different type of routes(1 for pedestrian, 1 for bike, 1 for car)